# Why mySQL database saves the string in small letters?

Tags: java, html, mysql, forms, mysql-workbench

Please help
I am trying to make a html application form. The user can fill out the form after that it will be saved in mySQL database. In html i have changed the text-transform: into capitalize, when you fill up the form you can see that the first letter is capitalized but in MySQL database, the letters are changed into small. Strange.

Comment: You should add a brief code excerpt from your application that demonstrates how you create the form and how you handle the text transformation. I guess your frontend transform the text in the view as it is displayed, but sends unaltered internal component value to the backend. It may be otherwise, but without code sample it's hard to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

CSS `text-transform` doesn't change the *value*. It affects how a value is *displayed* in the browser, but it doesn't affect the actual *value* of an element.

Why is MySQL storing lower case characters?  Because MySQL is storing the value that the INSERT statement is providing.

Why is the code providing a lower case value to the INSERT statement?  It's likely (and we're just guessing here without seeing any code) that the code is taking the value from the HTML form as is and using it in the INSERT statement.

And why are we getting a lower case value from the form?  Because that's the value on the form.

The behavior is as expected. Again, the CSS text-transform only affects what is displayed in the browser. It doesn't modify the value, just the display.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value to uppercase when inserting into the database or use something like this: `<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">`.

You will still need to include the CSS `text-transform: uppercase`, which will hide the sluggish behaviour of the JS.

```js
// Some Javascript to read what is typed in and show how it is converted

var input  = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var forEachEntryIn = function (array, callback, scope) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { callback.call(scope, i, array[i]); } };

function outputText() {
    output.innerHTML ='';
    forEachEntryIn( input, function (idx,el,sc) { output.innerHTML += 'text ' + (idx+1) + ': ' + el.value + '<br>'; });    
}

outputText() // first run
```

```css
body,input { font-size: 1.5rem }
.trans     { text-transform: uppercase }
```

```html
<h3>inputs</h3>
<label>text 1</label> <input class="trans" type="text" onkeyup="outputText();"><br>
<label>text 2</label> <input               type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();outputText();"><br>
<label>text 3</label> <input class="trans" type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();outputText();">

<h3>outputs</h3>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

could you explain what do yo save the data in Uppercase? Any way, if yo want yo can create a function with js to capture data of the input before you send this to msyql, and this way yo can validate if the data has o no a capitalize. Because the css only has effect in browser like a Sepencer7593